# Placing Value of Key defined in other variables key-value - Ansible

Tags: variables, ansible, yaml, jinja2

I am trying a simple scenario of managing users and their respective authorized_key values where some user may have inter-shared authorized_keys, any quick help to avoid the repetation which may occur in following :

file: roles/manageuser/var/main.yml

```
---
users:
  - username: user1
    ssh_key: "someExampleValidRSAPublicKEYValueInHereForAuthorizedKeys user1@localhost"

  - username: user2
    ssh_key: |
      someExampleValidRSAPublicKEYValueInHereForAuthorizedKeys user2@localhost
      someExampleValidRSAPublicKEYValueInHereForAuthorizedKeys user1@localhost
```

In above, I want to avoid repasting or repetation of user1 public-key under user2 section and to place it in via some filter or query or lookup over user1, for example :

`{{ query(users[?username=='user1'].ssh_key) }}` - DOESN'T WORK

`lookup('dict', ssh_key, users.username='user1')` - DOESN'T WORK EITHER

Can anyone guide me through this to using it correctly? Please note that I am trying to seed in value inside var/main.yml, so not sure how feasible that is as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. Quoting from [Can't reference a dict key inside the same dict #50280](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50280#issuecomment-450901757)

> *"This is expected and not something that we plan on changing. You cannot create a self referential variable."*

---

You might want to put the public keys into files and create an attribute with the list of lookups. For example

```yaml
users:
  - username: user1
    ssh_keys:
      - "{{ lookup('file', 'user1.localhost.pub') }}"
  - username: user2
    ssh_keys:
      - "{{ lookup('file', 'user1.localhost.pub') }}"
      - "{{ lookup('file', 'user2.localhost.pub') }}"
```

There is no overhead here. You have to reference all keys for a user anyway. Transform the lists to any format you need.

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir! Yes, that works as It covers the requirement and is fine if lookup from the same file. Appreciate your guidance.